# Rubyで@token&.userと書いたときの&の意味

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

githubで適当なRailsアプリケーションリポジトリのソースコードを見ていて、
@user = @token&.userという記述を見ました。

この＆はどういう意味なのでしょうか？
rails cで実行するとnilになりました

ちなみにuserのｍodelでは下のように設定しています。
has_one :token

@user.tokenなら素直にわかります。

特にテーブル定義などなくても回答には支障ないと思っているのですが、
必要なようでしたら教えてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ぼっち演算子`（これで検索するとたくさんの用法、用例がヒットします）と呼ばれるものです。

オブジェクトがnilの場合に`NoMethodError`を起こさないでnilを返します。

これにより、nil判定のコード量を減らせるなどのメリットがあり、メソッドチェーンなどがしやすくなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！すっきりしました。